# Node.js 12 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 16

Tags: nodejs, express, azure

Estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación construido con node.js en azure con centro de implementacion con origen en GitHub usando workflow. Pero al momento de hacer el build se cae.

[image: Como se ve en la imagen se cae por el test]

Answer (score 0):

Entonces lo que hice es modificar el test:
lo pasé de `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",`
a `"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\""`

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: Tu problema era que daba error... pero el error lo habías puesto tú ahí? Quiero decir, es obvio que va a dar error si tu le indicas que tire un error... es como arrancarle la batería a tu móvil y quejarte de que no enciende :)